# What happens to defunct questions?

Tags: discussion

Occasionally on SO, a question will be asked which isn’t necessarily clear.  There is often some initial activity where questions are asked in comments which are answered, but after a while the question may become dormant.

For example the person asking the question has ignored the last few comments / questions raised about the question they asked.  Is there a point at which the question should be considered dead/defunct/unanswerable?  Is there any etiquette around how long to give the questioner?  Does this change if it’s an individual’s first question (some people seem to log on, ask a question, get distracted and go somewhere else)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If they meet the criteria outlined in [Auto-deleting old, unanswered zero-score questions after a year?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/auto-deleting-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year) then they're automatically removed.

If a question doesn't meet those criteria, then the activity probably warrants keeping it around.  The original author isn't the only one who might add more details or clarify a question.  Anyone who's had the same problem or a very similar problem can edit those details in.